# How to pick file from /data/data/ path from a device

Tags: android

I have created a file in the below path using my applcation.

/data/data/VisionEPODErrorLog/ErrorLog.txt

I am able to see  the file using Eclipse DDMS->File Explore ->Data

But when I installed my applcation in the mob device I am not getting that path in the device.

I need to see the exact file in the device

Is there any third party applcation needed to access the path.If so whats that or is there any way else to get that file from the device.if anyone konws please let me konw

Answer (score 0):

please use below method

```
        BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(Mtx.getContext().openFileInput("ErrorLog.txt"));
```

i used in my application to read file stored under /data/data/ directory

i think this will help

Comment: Sorry I mean I need to see the exact file in the device

Comment: I think you may have administrative power( ie device is rooted) to see the exact file in the device

Answer (score 0):

> /data/data/VisionEPODErrorLog/ErrorLog.txt

That is an exceptionally bad idea. Please do not do that. Please use `getFilesDir()` to get the root of your internal storage for files.

> But when I installed my applcation in the mob device I am not getting that path in the device.

You should not be able to write there on a production device. Please do not invent random paths. Please use `getFilesDir()` to get the root of your internal storage for files.

You certainly cannot view anything in `/data/data` on a production device via any tool, unless you root your phone.